# How to implement Circular iCarosel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, menu

> I tried all the ways by setting the respective value's but i'm unable
>   get below one by using iCaurosel,or is there any controller which gives same functionality
>   ? can you help me?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/mpospese/CircleLayout please check this

Answer (score 0):

You should choose iCarousel type to wheel:

```
self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeWheel;
```

but if you mean items margin, this is not possible:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/306

Comment: if we are going with this one it'l give cirler wheel but backside part ovelapped by front view.

Comment: have you tried to change the view hierarchy:


    bringSubviewToFront:,
    sendSubviewToBack:,
    insertSubview:atIndex:,
    insertSubview:aboveSubview:,
    insertSubview:belowSubview:,
    exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:,

Comment: can you post your implementation code, so we can help you to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following sample. this is dynamic circles (views) you can add.:)

https://github.com/mpospese/CircleLayout

Happy coding.

Comment: no it's not useful for me here there is no scrolling option

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same functionality by creating the custom circular UICollectionView layout.Please visit the following link to solve this.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `carousel.type = iCarouselTypeWheel` and then using the `carousel:valueForOption:withDefault:` delegate method to adjust circle radius, number of items shown, etc.

To position the circle off-center like that, use `carousel.contentOffset`.

You may find that the gesture handling is a bit weird though, because the pan gesture will still be linear even though the view appears circular.